# "In response to" or "in responses to"?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number

Is *in responses to* a correct usage? I use *in response to* when the amount of subjects is one and *in responses to* when the amount of subjects is more than one. For example:

> In response to A, B does...
>   In responses to A, B and C do...

Or should it be:

> In response to A, B does one thing.
>   In responses to A, B does two things.

Which usage is correct?

Comment: [Guess](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+response+to%2Cin+responses+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20response%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20responses%20to%3B%2Cc0). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singular *in response*. You may be responding to multiple items, but you are still composing a single *response*.

Comment: But the context is not defined well enough to completely rule out the plural here: A survey was conducted in which 1000 participants where asked to look at a diagram and determine what B does.  As determined by over 800 responses to the survey, B does two things...

Answer (score 0):

How many responses do you compose? One, so you must write all the time *in response to*.